# subsetting the first row of each element in a variable

Tags: r, subset, uniqueidentifier

I have this dataset shown below

`Name            ID       DATES      R
1   @0CC        71476   20000704    11
2   @0CC        71476   20001204    11
3   @0RM        49960   20000131    2
4   @0RM        73565   20000919    1
5   @0RM        59451   20001023    1
6   @0RM        44457   20001214    1
7   @0TL        48061   20000627    31
8   @0TL        19824   20000929    3
9   @0TL        70970   20001211    1
10  @0TL        73862   20001212    2
11  @0TL        48061   20001227    31
12  @1AJ        58875   20001214    1
13  @1AJ        56014   20001214    3
14  @1AJ        47340   20001214    3
15  @1AJ        19813   20001214    3
16  @1AL        44416   20000303    31
17  @1AL        59184   20000413    323
18  @1AL        44416   20000517    31
19  @1AL        52718   20000621    1
20  @1AL        59184   20000707    323
21  @1AL        59184   20000801    323
22  @1AL        72832   20001127    43
23  @1AL        73568   20001130    3
24  @1AL        72832   20001211    43
25  @1FF        58781   20000719    1
26  @1FF        44505   20000801    12
27  @1FF        73559   20001110    1
28  @1FF        44505   20001218    12
29  @1FF        47276   20001227    3`

What i'm trying to do is that for each unique name, and each unique ID, i would like to create a subset of this data frame, e.g

`Name           ID        DATES     R
1   @0CC        71476   20000704    11
3   @0RM        49960   20000131    2
4   @0RM        73565   20000919    1
5   @0RM        59451   20001023    1
6   @0RM        44457   20001214    1
7   @0TL        48061   20000627    31
8   @0TL        19824   20000929    3
9   @0TL        70970   20001211    1
10  @0TL        73862   20001212    2
12  @1AJ        58875   20001214    1
13  @1AJ        56014   20001214    3
14  @1AJ        47340   20001214    3
15  @1AJ        19813   20001214    3
16  @1AL        44416   20000303    31
17  @1AL        59184   20000413    323
19  @1AL        52718   20000621    1
22  @1AL        72832   20001127    43
23  @1AL        73568   20001130    3
25  @1FF        58781   20000719    1
26  @1FF        44505   20000801    12
27  @1FF        73559   20001110    1
29  @1FF        47276   20001227    3`

I am thinking of using two for loops

```
for(i in unique(noanalysttest$IBTKR2)){
for(j in unique(noanalysttest$AMASKCD)){
R2<-subset(DT)
}
R2
```

But this doesn't give me the right solution. Much help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: @Frank thanks for pointing out the duplicate, i was reading through that thread and i tried ``df1[!duplicated(df1[c("Name", "ID")]),]`` which did not work but ``unique(setDT(df1), by = c("Name", "ID"))`` does after looking at @akrun solution. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `slice` from `dplyr` after grouping by 'Name' and 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Name, ID) %>%
    slice(1)
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be

```
df1[!duplicated(df1[c("Name", "ID")]),]
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1), by = c("Name", "ID"))
```

Or as @Frank suggested

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[1L], by = .(Name, ID)]
```

Comment: @Frank Is it, i thought it was faster.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: thanks alot for your help!